# correlation of one variable to all the other in R

Tags: r, correlation

I want to calculate the correlation between my dependent variable y and all my x. I use the code below,

```
   cor(loan_data_10v[sapply(loan_data_10v, is.numeric)],use="complete.obs")
```

the result is a correlation matrix.
How can i just get one column with my variable y.

Comment: `cor(load_data_10v)[,1]`?

Comment: it throw me an error "'x' must be numeric", since not all the variables in my data set are numeric

Comment: My point: add `[,1]` to the outside/end of your command, add in `cor(...)[,1]`.

Comment: Yes this works too. Thank you!!!

Comment: Since my y is the 10, i used [,10], it works. what if i dont know my y is the 10 th, but the last one, i tried [,-1], but this gave me everything. Why i that, i thought it is going to slice the last column

Comment: Sorry, I have no idea what you are talking about. `[,-1]` gives you all columns *except* 1, that's [what negatives are intended to do](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/Extract.html).

Comment: okay got it thank you!

Answer (score 24, accepted):

If we are looking for `cor` between 'x' and 'y', both argument can be either a `vector` or `matrix`.  using a reproducible example, say `mtcars` and suppose 'y' is 'mpg' and 'x' the other variables ('mpg' is the first column, so we used `mtcars[-1]` for 'x')

```
cor(mtcars[-1], mtcars$mpg) 
#          [,1]
#cyl  -0.8521620
#disp -0.8475514
#hp   -0.7761684
#drat  0.6811719
#wt   -0.8676594
#qsec  0.4186840
#vs    0.6640389
#am    0.5998324
#gear  0.4802848
#carb -0.5509251
```

---

If we have `numeric/non-numeric` columns, create an index of `numeric` columns ('i1'), get the `names` of 'x' and 'y' variables using this index and apply the `cor`

```
i1 <- sapply(loan_data_10v, is.numeric)
y1 <- "dep_column" #change it to actual column name
x1 <- setdiff(names(loan_data_10v)[i1], y1)
cor(loan_data_10v[x1], loan_data_10v[[y1]])
```

Comment: Thank you! it work. I add use="complete.obs" in the cor, since i have na value in each of my varaible

Comment: Hey akrun, would there be anyway to achieve this solution with data.table? I posted a question about it here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56182271/getting-the-correlation-with-significance-of-one-variable-with-the-rest-of-the-d

Answer (score 1):

Another option is the [corrr](https://corrr.tidymodels.org/) package where you can specify the variable you want to `focus` on easily which returns a `data.frame`:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(corrr)
mtcars %>% 
  correlate() %>% 
  focus(mpg) 
# Correlation computed with
# • Method: 'pearson'
# • Missing treated using: 'pairwise.complete.obs'
# # A tibble: 10 × 2
#    term     mpg
#    <chr>  <dbl>
#  1 cyl   -0.852
#  2 disp  -0.848
#  3 hp    -0.776
#  4 drat   0.681
#  5 wt    -0.868
#  6 qsec   0.419
#  7 vs     0.664
#  8 am     0.600
#  9 gear   0.480
# 10 carb  -0.551
```

Its also useful if you want to remove other non-numeric variables first e.g.:

```
iris %>% 
  select_if(~!is.factor(.)) %>% 
  correlate() %>% 
  focus(Petal.Width)
# Correlation computed with
# • Method: 'pearson'
# • Missing treated using: 'pairwise.complete.obs'
# # A tibble: 3 × 2
#   term         Petal.Width
#   <chr>              <dbl>
# 1 Sepal.Length       0.818
# 2 Sepal.Width       -0.366
# 3 Petal.Length       0.963
```