# R result of cor() function

Tags: r

I want to subset just one line of cor() matrix

when I run the cor() function, It gives me this result

ex)

```
   a  b  c  d  e
a  1  2  3  4  5
b  5  1  3  2  1
c  2  3  1  5  6
d  1  1  1  1  1
e  1  1  1  1  1
```

I only want this section

```
   a  b  c  d  e
a  1  2  3  4  5
```

or

```
  b  c  d  e
a 2  3  4  5
```

Any Suggestion?

I tried result[1, 1:5] but the result was

```
a  b  c  d  e
1  2  3  4  5
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7352254/how-to-subset-matrix-to-one-column-maintain-matrix-data-type-maintain-row-colu

Comment: you can find the correlation of one variable against the others - [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45892274/correlation-of-one-variable-to-all-the-other-in-r)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try `result[1, 2:5, drop=FALSE]`. The `drop` should let you retain the row name.

Comment: Thanks for your answer sir !! It works well